# Adding the name of the parent transaction controller into each row of the jmeter results

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know if its possible to output the name of the parent transaction controller against each row in the jmeter results? I current have enabled "Generate Parent Sample" which gives an independent row for each parent but it doesn't allow me to easily find the associated transaction controller for each individual child row. I know they appear in order but when executing many threads its quite difficult to see and even more difficult to generate automated reporting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to apply the "Naming Policy" and uncheck the "Generate parent sample" from the transaction controller. This will update the child names with respect to the parent transaction controller with count appended at end of the http request. More Reference - [LINK](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#transaction_controller_requirements)

OR
You have to manually append the "Transaction Controller" name against the underline Http Requests.

```
1. Transaction Controller1
    a. Http Request1 - Transaction Controller1
    b. Http Request2 - Transaction Controller1
2. Transaction Controller2
    a. Http Request1 - Transaction Controller2
    b. Http Request2 - Transaction Controller2
```